# Trouble with understanding quotient maps

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

> Show that the cone $c(S^n)$ is homeomorphic to $\overline{B}^{n+1}$.

The cone is defined as $c(S^n) = (S^n \times I)/(S^n \times\{1\})$. The book I'm reading says that this quotient comes with a projection $p:S^n \times I \to S^n \times\{1\}$ such that $$p(x)= \begin{cases} S^n \times\{1\}, &x \in S^n \times\{1\} \\ \{x\}, &x \in S^n \times I \setminus (S^n \times\{1\}) \end{cases}$$

Pictorially I see that the cone formed for example from $S^1$ is just the regular solid we have on $\Bbb R^3$, but I don't understand how does this mapping $p$ work? It doesn't seem to map the cylinder $S^1 \times I$ to the cone? All the points on top of the cylinder lying on $S^1 \times\{1\}$ are just mapped to the set itself and all other points to the singletons $\{x\}$?

How should I interpret this $p$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> It's a little hard to tell from the wording: You're aware the _cone_ is the _lateral surface_ (not the solid), which is homeomorphic to the closed unit disk...?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the target space is a quotient by an equivalence relation on $S^n\times I$ (namely that given by $(x, s)\sim(y, t)$ if $(x, s)=(y, t)$ or $s=1=t$), so the points in the cone are actually *equivalence classes of the points* in the cylinder instead of *the points* in the cylinder. This is why it looks like it is sending a point to itself, but it actually does not. It sends a point $(x, t)$ with $0\le t<1$ to the equivalence class $[(x, t)]=\{(x, t)\}\neq(x, t)$. The quotient topology is also defined in a way that corresponds to the equivalence classes of $(x, t)$ getting closer and closer to each other as $t$ gets closer to 1. Also, note that even though $S^n\times\{1\}$ is a set by itself, it is actually also the case that $[(x, 1)]=S^n\times\{1\}$ for any $x\in S^n$. So, what this means is that the set that is being collapsed to a point actually does become an *element* in the quotient space (or its underlying set) instead of being a subset like it originally was. What $p$ then does is that it takes any $(x, t)\in S^n\times I$ and sends it to $[(x, t)]$. If $t=1$, then this does not depend on $x$ but is always sent to the same element, $S^n\times\{1\}\in c(S^n)$.

Hope this helps! $(\ ^\circ\smile^\circ)$